# How to access contacts in macOS without error

Tags: swift, macos, contacts

Trying to fetch the contact list from macOS Contacts using Swift in Xcode 10.1. I get a path error.

I'm using the recommended approach and have included the privacy key in Info.plist.

```
func getAllContacts() {
    let status = CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: CNEntityType.contacts) as CNAuthorizationStatus
    print(status)

    //   if status == CNAuthorizationStatus.denied {
    //       showAccessContactsDeniedAlert()
    //       return
    //   }
    let contactStore = CNContactStore()

    let keysToFetch = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNPostalAddressStreetKey, CNPostalAddressCityKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
    let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch:keysToFetch as [CNKeyDescriptor])
    do {
        try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact:CNContact, stop:UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
            print("\(contact.familyName) \(contact.givenName) ")

        })
    } catch {
        //catch
    }
```

Here is what I get:

> 2019-05-13 23:54:10.586962+0200 Show Clients[2324:83437] [default] Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)
>   CNAuthorizationStatus
>   2019-05-13 23:54:30.347100+0200 Show Clients[2324:83437] Could not get real path for Address Book lock folder: open() for F_GETPATH failed.
>   2019-05-13 23:54:30.347101+0200 Show Clients[2324:83437] Unable to open file lock: {recursion count = 0, name = nil}, fileDescriptor=-1> Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=14 "Bad address" UserInfo={ABFileDescriptor=-1}

Comment: The error dissapears when I turn Sandboxing capability on with "Contact" App Data selected and turn Sandboxing off again.